# msysgit git clone ignores ssh config

Tags: windows, git, ssh, msysgit, openssh

I've installed msysgit and git uses proper ssh.exe. All commands are executed in msysgit shell (program files x86 sh.exe).
Then i set my ~/.ssh/config file to this

```
LogLevel DEBUG1

Host bitbucket.com
  HostName bitbucket.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile /d/ssh/bitbucket.ppk
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then `ssh bitbucket.com` works well:

```
$ ssh bitbucket.com
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.com [131.103.20.173] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /d/ssh/bitbucket.ppk type -1
debug1: identity file /d/ssh/bitbucket.ppk-cert type -1
```

but when i try to `git clone git@bitbucket.org:User/reponame.git` ssh debug messages shows me that ssh don't even try to pick bitbucket ppk, instead trying to use default keys:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/reponame.git
Cloning into 'reponame'...
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
```

I'm out of ideas.

```
$ where git
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone git@bitbucket.org:User/reponame.git` would look for `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, not for `/d/ssh/bitbucket.ppk`.

What should work (since `ssh bitbucket.com` does work) is:

```
git clone bitbucket.com:User/reponame.git
```

That would actually use the parameters defined in the `~/.ssh/config` file.

`bitbucket.com` is the entry in the config file (it could be named anything really), but the `HostName` must be indeed `bitbucket.org`, which is the domain where the Git repos are stored.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was my own inattention. Bitbucket uses bitbucket.org for repos. Afaik, before it used bitbucket.com.

Comment: I agree. I have added that in my answer to be complete.